# Электронные права на фото

Tags: лицензирование, seo

Добрый день.

Есть такая проблема, наша компания производит и поставляет продукцию дилерам и реализует её самостоятельно.

У товара есть название, которое используют дилеры (и нелицензионные дилеры) и фотография(ии), которая была сфотографирована НАМИ.
Проблема в том, что когда мы вбиваем в поиск google, yandex названия нашей компании, сферы деятельности, товаров и т.д. То на первых страницах картинок поисковиков присутствует 80% наших фотографий, однако большинство из них ссылаются на другие сайты, из которых только 20% наши официальны дилеры. Ссылка на нашу компанию находится на 3-4 странице и то только 1-2 фотографии.
Хотя у нас есть собственный интернет-гипермаркет с множеством фотографий товаров и их подробным описанием, тем же названием.

1) Хотелось бы знать, можно ли довести количество наших фотографий с ссылками на наш сайт на первых страницах до приемлемого уровня?

2) Большинство ссылок ведут на нелицензированных дилеров, которые используют наши фотографии, однако непонятно, какой товар они поставляют, так как цены там могут быть существенно ниже. Можно ли как-то воздействовать на сайты, использующие нашу собственность (фото) в своих целях?

Что можете посоветовать? Ведь если бы ссылки вели на наш сайт, то количество заказов было бы больше, ведь это наша продукция и нам выгоднее продавать её напрямую.

ПРИМЕР:
Допустим, что 80% этих скамеек и их ***фото*** делаем мы и поставляем их другим компаниям, однако ссылки ведут на всевозможные другие сайты.

[image]

3) У google есть раздел "Права на использование", можно ли как-то зарегистрировать электронные права на фотографию, чтобы с чужих (нелицензионных) сайтов она (фотография) исчезла и запросы на адрес этого сайта упали бы?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Если на других сайтах есть предложения об изготовлении более дешевых скамеек сравнимого с вашим качества, то люди будут покупать у них вне зависимости от того, пиратские у них фото этих скамеек или нет. Вам надо подумать, как удешевить продукцию, а вовсе не о правах на фото. Будете делать дешево и качественно - будут заказы.
2. По поводу прав на фотографии - обратитесь к юристам. Вам помогут составить образец письма и заявление в суд. Затем ищите владельцев сайтов, которые используют ваши фото, связывайтесь и просите мирным путем убрать фотографии. Если реакции нет, то отправляйте заказное письмо с уведомлением с претензией по адресу владельца сайта. Затем, при неизменности ситуации - подавайте заявление в суд. В общем, дело долгое и муторное. У владельца сайта всегда будет объяснение, что он знать не знал о вас и взял эти фотографии, например, на fishki.net или еще где-нибудь, где они были указаны как бесплатные. Да, вам еще нужно будет доказать ваше авторство или права владения фотографиями.

В целом как-то так.
Вообще, все, что вы выложили в открытый доступ в Интернет становится достоянием общественности. Вы можете указать свое авторство на фото и указать, что копирование запрещено, но как-либо повлиять на других людей и принудить их не копировать фотографии, которые они видят в своем браузере, невозможно.